# aws alb path rewrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Need help how to do it.

Prerequisites:
I have nodejs app with webpack serving client in development. In development I rewrite path

```
   proxy: {
        '/monitor': {
            target: 'http://localhost:2222',
            pathRewrite: { '^/monitor': '' },
        },
    }
```

When I deployed in managed environment I use nginx for something similar

```
location ~ ^/monitor/ {
    rewrite ^/monitor/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Now I deployed my app in aws in docker container on ec2 instance.  I want to rewrite path, stripping monitor part. I don't want to change the client as I hope to have working environments everywhere, locally, on managed server and in aws

I tried to create a new rule to my alb target group

rewrite
Path Pattern is /monitor/*
Redirect to HTTPS://#{host}:443/$1?#{query}
Status code: HTTP_301

but this doesn't help much

Comment: ALB doesn't do path rewrites at all. You still need Nginx running on the EC2 server to handle this.